# I'm unable to traverse the DOM from an <img> to a <td>...?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors, dom-traversal, replacewith

#### Overview

I greatly appreciate any help with this. I'm sure it's "easy" but I can't figure it out. I am having to use selectors to choose a unique image file name. I'm then needing to replace the `<td>` that is one column to the right of the `<td>` that the `<img>` is in.

I have the current website and I also made a diagram to help explain this better. Check the following two links: 
Website: http://www.writeguard.com/catalog/Checks/LaserInkjet-Checks
Diagram: http://goo.gl/Q3Uif

#### The Problem

The link to the website above doesn't have a problem. We have a "franchise" custom modification in our oscommerce. Only customers with certain accounts can log into where I'm needing help. The diagram I made describes it, simply enough. Just so you have all the "pieces" of my "puzzle", here is how I'm doing the `.replaceWIth()` for the main site. This example is for the top row...I have one of these for every row I need to modify.

```
 $("a[href$=/Premium-Security-Laser-Check].smallTextLink").parent()
 .replaceWith('<td class="productListing-data" style="border-left:1px solid #FFF; border-top:1px solid #FFF; border-bottom:1px solid #808080; border-right:1px solid #808080;"><div class="leftSide"><a href="http://www.writeguard.com/catalog/Checks/LaserInkjet-Checks/Premium-Security-Laser-Check" class="smallTextLink">Premium Security Laser Check</a><ul style="line-height: 1.5em; font-size: 11px; margin-left: -15px;"><li style="color:red;"><strong>Buy 500 Checks, Get 500 Free Special!</strong></li><li>More than 8 security features</li><li>Thermochromic Ink</li><li>8.5" x 11" sheet 24lb MICR paper</li><li>2 perforations @ 3.5" x 7"</li></ul><div class="moreInfoButtonsNew"><a href="http://www.writeguard.com/catalog/Checks/LaserInkjet-Checks/Premium-Security-Laser-Check" class="positive"><img src="http://writeguard.com/catalog/images/new_layout/icons/information.png" alt=""/>More Info</a></div></div><div class="rightSide"><p class="ourPrice">Starting At:<br>$39.50</p></div></td>');
```

That is not efficient at all, I assume. But just for this problem I'm having now, I need to be able to do what I described at the top. Select the `<img>` by it's filename, then navigate the DOM so I can use `.replaceWith()` to achieve the same thing I described above. I've tried a lot of different selectors but none of them work. It always ends up making table data inside table data inside table data until the page is literally 10 feet long. I don't know where I'm going wrong.

I can happily provide more details if necessary. I'm obviously not very experienced with jQuery and my methods are probably a nightmare. I want to learn the correct, efficient way to program with jquery soon. THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOUR HELP!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with your selector.

I don't believe `$("a[href$=/Premium-Security-Laser-Check].smallTextLink")` will actually grab anything.

Try this:

```
$('a.smallTextLink[href$="Premium-Security-Laser-Check"]').click(function()
{
    alert('clicked the security laster check small text link');
});
```

If that works, then you should be able to just change your selector and have your replacewith work.

`$('a.smallTextLink[href=/Premium-Security-Laser-Check]').parent()
 .replaceWith('<td class="productListing-data" style="border-left:1px solid #FFF; border-top:1px solid #FFF; border-bottom:1px solid #808080; border-right:1px solid #808080;"><div class="leftSide"><a href="http://www.writeguard.com/catalog/Checks/LaserInkjet-Checks/Premium-Security-Laser-Check" class="smallTextLink">Premium Security Laser Check</a><ul style="line-height: 1.5em; font-size: 11px; margin-left: -15px;"><li style="color:red;"><strong>Buy 500 Checks, Get 500 Free Special!</strong></li><li>More than 8 security features</li><li>Thermochromic Ink</li><li>8.5" x 11" sheet 24lb MICR paper</li><li>2 perforations @ 3.5" x 7"</li></ul><div class="moreInfoButtonsNew"><a href="http://www.writeguard.com/catalog/Checks/LaserInkjet-Checks/Premium-Security-Laser-Check" class="positive"><img src="http://writeguard.com/catalog/images/new_layout/icons/information.png" alt=""/>More Info</a></div></div><div class="rightSide"><p class="ourPrice">Starting At:<br>$39.50</p></div></td>');`

Comment: The selector should be written like: $('a[href$="Premium-Security-Laser-Check"].smallTextLink') or $('a.smallTextLink[href$="Premium-Security-Laser-Check"]'). The one you have doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding! I have been out of the office but will try the suggestions that I have received and post what worked. Again, much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The selector should be:

```
$('a.smallTextLink[href$="Premium-Security-Laser-Check"]')
```

And the structure of your table, you have:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <div>
      <a href='....'>
      ..
      ..
```

So your jQuery statement needs to find the parent that is a td. parent() is returning the div. You wants parents('td:first') to grab the first parent that is a td element.

```
$('a[href$="Premium-Security-Laser-Check"].smallTextLink').parents('td:first')
  .replaceWith(....)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have been out of the office but will try this out ASAP. It seems like it should work! Thanks again!!